# How to create a CVXPY Variable with discontinuous range?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to optimize a inventory control linear program for month to month over a year.  I cannot figure out how to program a variable that can either be 0 or greater than 50.  I have three purchase options for tshirts, less than 25 at $30 a shirt, between 25 and 49 at $25 a shirt, and greater than 50 shirts at $20 a shirt.  The variable that I have created for how many shirts I buy with the $20 a shirt bundle is only able to be 0 (if I don't purchase any shirts as part of this bundle for the month) or 50+.  The code I have is as follows:

```
z = cp.Variable(12, integer = True)  #z[i] = number of tshirts bought at lowest price after month i
constraints.append(z[0] >= 50 OR z[0] == 0)        #Cannot buy less than 50 tshirts at this price
```

If I separate them and put z[0] == 0 first I believe it'll be written over with a value > 50 when solved, if I put it 2nd will it reset the solved value?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#semi-continuous-variables

Answer (score 0):

A variable `x` with `x=0 or x≥50` is called a semicontinuous variable. Many tools and solvers have direct support for this. CVXPY does not.

Instead, we can use an additional binary variable `δ ∈ {0,1}` and use:

```
  50 ⋅ δ ≤ x ≤ U ⋅ δ
  δ ∈ {0,1}
  x ∈ [0,U]
```

where `U` is an upper bound on `x`.